# How to have a separate page? What should be the link to that page?

Tags: pages

I want to have a separate php page. What should be an anchor for that page if i'm placing the link on home page? Suppose my page name is projects.php, but when I put it in an anchor tag like , it doesn't go to that page.

I'm guessing there must be some wordpress function before "projects.php" in order to work correctly.

This is the hierarchy of my theme:
myTheme

```
│   .jscsrc
│   .jshintignore
│   404.php
│   archive.php
│   comments.php
│   footer.php
│   frontpage.php
│   functions.php
│   header.php
│   index.php
│   mypage.php
│   options.php
│   page.php
│   people.php
│   projects.php
│   README.md
│   readme.txt
│   rtl.css
│   screenshot.png
│   search.php
│   sidebar.php
│   single-projects.php
│   single-timeline.php
│   single.php
│   style.css
│   timeline.php
│   
├───assets
│   ├───css
│   │       base.css
│   │       bootstrap.css
│   │       bootstrap.min.css
│   │       common.css
│   │       demo.css
│   │       normalize.css
│   │       style-old.css
│   │       style.css
│   │       style7.css
│   │       
│   ├───icons
│   │       icon-top.png
│   │       sprite.png
│   │       
│   ├───img
│   │       216x217.png
│   │       annual-report.png
│   │       arrows.png
│   │       bgimg.jpg
│   │       kenya.jpg
│   │       kenya2.jpg
│   │       kenya3.jpg
│   │       logo.png
│   │       malaria.jpg
│   │       malaria2.jpg
│   │       malaria3.jpg
│   │       malaria4.jpg
│   │       spr-general.png
│   │       sprite-black.png
│   │       sprite.png
│   │       white_texture.jpg
│   │       
│   └───js
│           modernizr.custom.79639.js
│           
├───inc
│       custom-header.php
│       customizer.php
│       extras.php
│       jetpack.php
│       template-tags.php
│       
├───js
│       navigation.js
│       scroll.js
│       skip-link-focus-fix.js
│       
├───languages
│       novar.pot
│       readme.txt
│       
├───layouts
│       content-sidebar.css
│       sidebar-content.css
│       
├───lib
│       custom-post-type.php
│       
├───metaboxes
├───options-framework
│   │   options-framework.php
│   │   
│   ├───css
│   │       optionsframework.css
│   │       
│   ├───images
│   │       ico-delete.png
│   │       
│   ├───includes
│   │       class-options-framework-admin.php
│   │       class-options-framework.php
│   │       class-options-interface.php
│   │       class-options-media-uploader.php
│   │       class-options-sanitization.php
│   │       
│   └───js
│           media-uploader.js
│           options-custom.js
│           
└───template-parts
        content-none.php
        content-page.php
        content-search.php
        content.php
```

I want to link the projects.php page in footer.php

Comment: You can check it .
[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810124/how-to-add-a-php-page-to-wordpress)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1 (Treating it as a Wordpress page):**

1) Add following on the top of projects.php

```
/*
Template Name: Projects
*/
```

2) Create a page from wordpress and select 'Projects' as its template from the right menu

3) Now you have a project page. Use its URL in anchor like you use other wordpress pages' URL.

**Method 2 (Not treating it as a wordpress page)**

```
<a href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/projects.php">Link Text</a>
```

For more info about `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` function:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri

Comment: What a great answer I must say. (y) Thank you so much :)

Comment: It should perhaps be mentioned that if you're using method 2, you're most likely doing something wrong.